# I have many backlink from other sites too one page of my site with hidden iframe. Has a positive or negative impact?

Tags: seo, pagerank, backlinks, google-ranking, iframe

am sorry for my bad english. i have a site for download free website templates. i create a simple html file in my site and put my histats & google analitic code on that. then put a hidden iframe to this page in the free templates like this :(To increase the number of visitors to my site)

```
<IFRAME style="display:none;" SRC="http://www.domain.com/df/sdff.html" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1></IFRAME>
```

now after two years i have about 60000 daily visitors just to this one page from many of sites who using my free templates. please answer me step by step 1- is this backling The negative or positive effect for my site ranking & seo ? 2- who to i can delet this page from my site No further negative impact to my site ? 3- who to i can reject this backlink from my server ? because if this page will be delet all of the back link redirect to 404 page & this page in my site is large & The server puts a lot of pressure. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no affect or effect, I think as Google doesn't follow Iframe's content. See more [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/72746?query=iframe&topic=&type=#4)

Comment: yes google dont follow this . but this visitors when see a site with my site iframe. like this visitor visit my site beacause in my page is a google analitic code & histats code & ...

Comment: Yes, you got hit count but there is no positive or negative impact on your site's seo since Google doesn't follow iframe. So, the answer to your question is "NO".

Answer (score 0):

I remember the old day when I do link building by sponsoring WP themes. Well, it goods for your to see backlinks gaining everyday. But when Google sent me a "Love" letter, I start to worried.

Google consider it as a bad linking and should be avoided. If not your site will be penalized. That was happened on me. Seeing your ranking drop to nowhere makes your life miserable. My advice, just DON'T do it!

Comment: If I understand correctly: I would avoid these back links. but you dont answer my Second question:  2- who to i can delet this page from my site No further negative impact to my site ? 3- who to i can reject this backlink from my server ? because if this page will be delet all of the back link redirect to 404 page & this page in my site is large & The server puts a lot of pressure. please help me. thanks